# How can I get the count of each row using an inner join? Getting an error that a column doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to get the sum of order_sum column as well as the sum of order_sum where the payment_method is cash and card seperately. But I'm getting an error that a column does not exist.

Any help would be much appreciated!

> Unknown column 'table2.id' in 'on clause'

Here is my `orders` table

```
+----+-----------+----------------+------------+---------------------+
| id | order_sum | payment_method | is_deleted | created_at          |
+----+-----------+----------------+------------+---------------------+
| 1  | 123       | cash           | 0          | 2019-12-15 12:05:38 |
| 2  | 456       | card           | 0          | 2019-12-16 17:45:11 |
| 3  | 789       | cash           | 0          | 2019-12-16 20:14:59 |
+----+-----------+----------------+------------+---------------------+
```

And here is my query so far..

```
SELECT
    sum(order_sum) as order_sum,
    count(*) as count,
    DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y-%m-%e') as date,
    table2.cash_sum
FROM
    orders
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        sum(order_sum) as cash_sum,
        DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y-%m-%e') as date
    FROM
        orders
    WHERE payment_method = 'cash'
    GROUP BY
        date
) as table2 on orders.id = table2.id
where
    is_deleted = 0
group by
    date 
order by date
```

The desired result would look like this

```
+------------+-----------+----------+----------+
| date       | order_sum | cash_sum | card_sum |
+------------+-----------+----------+----------+
| 2019-12-15 | 579       | 123      | 0        |
| 2019-12-16 | 1245      | 789      | 456      |
+------------+-----------+----------+----------+
```

Comment: The error is because you have not selected id in the sub query.  - using a sub query is the wrong approach see conditional aggregation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be achieved with conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y-%m-%e') as date,
       sum(order_sum) as order_sum,
       sum(CASE WHEN payment_method = 'cash' THEN order_sum END) as cash_sum,
       sum(CASE WHEN payment_method = 'card' THEN order_sum END) as card_sum,
       count(*) as count
FROM orders
where is_deleted = 0
group by DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y-%m-%e')
order by date
```

Comment: the condition should depend on the payment_method, I think?